# Does the Day Picker Input calendar only open down and to the right?

Tags: css, react-day-picker

The calendar (so far) doesn't seem to account for collision detection when deciding the position of the calendar. For example :

[image]

In the screen shot you can see that the calendar goes off screen. Even if I disable horizontal scroll (`overflow-x: hidden;`), it still renders off screen.

Is there a solution to this without hacking away at the styles?

Comment: Via CSS is a bit difficult, if not impossible, since to move the overlay on the left you will need to know the window's size. 

Another user had a similar issue: https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/issues/536, see my comment there :)

Answer (score 0):

react-day-picker's [DayPickerInput API](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput#classNames) now has **classNames** which allows you to change the name of the classes for the overlay and the overlay wrapper. You are basically renaming them so that in your own **CSS/LESS** file, you can use that name to style the overlay and have it use that instead of the classes in the react-day-picker-style.css (which you should **not** try to change as a best practice).

If you want to change the default props for the overlay (calendar popup), then you would do something like this wherever you are creating the component:

```
createElement(DayPicker.Input,
    { //all other props 
        classNames: {
            overlay: "TheNewNameForTheClass", 
            overlayWrapper: "TheOtherNewNameForTheClass" 
        } 
    }
})
```

And then in your styling file, you would use `TheNewNameForTheClass` and `TheOtherNewNameForTheClass` to style the overlay.

Comment: The solution would have been collision detection. While this isn’t a bad enhancement in the library it’s a small shortcoming

Comment: I totally agree with you, @MarkC.